# How do I determine what is waking my machine up?

Tags: sleep-wake, logs

Recently my Macbook Pro has been waking up from sleep at undesirable times (middle of the night) without any user interaction (nobody has touched it).

Is there a log on the machine that records the reason a machine woke from sleep?

Apparently the machine wakes up because:

```
1/26/14, 1:21:20 AM PST  Wake  Wake [CDNVA] due to EHC1/HID Activity: Using AC (Charge:99%)
```

What is `[CDNVA] due to EHC1/HID Activity: Using AC (Charge:99%)`?

Comment: Have you checked the Wake for Network Access checkbox in the Power Adapter tab of Energy Saver Preference Pane ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EHC is Enhanced Host Controller. It's a USB interface, similar to OHC. However EHC can also be wireless devices and Bluetooth since they are also on the USB bus of a Mac.

HID is a Human Interface Device, such as mice/keyboards. Bluetooth HID could be the culprit.

Try disconnecting **all USB and Bluetooth devices, and turn off Airport**, then attempt to sleep it.

Comment: Ok, so I have determined it is a Bluetooth device that is waking the machine up! Is there a way to look up Device IDs or do I just need to manually troubleshoot by turning individual devices off?

Comment: @nipponese Trial and error with individual devices is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `pmset -g log` to see a log of power events:

```
$ pmset -g log|grep Wake|tail
1/25/14, 13:50:42 GMT+2  WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: None
1/25/14, 15:16:52 GMT+2  Wake                   Wake [CDNVA] due to XHC1/HID Activity: Using AC
Sleep/Wakes since boot at 1/24/14, 20:39:59 GMT+2  :2   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:0
1/25/14, 22:48:51 GMT+2  WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: None
1/25/14, 23:23:12 GMT+2  Wake                   Wake [CDNVA] due to XHC1/HID Activity: Using AC                             4397 secs
Sleep/Wakes since boot at 1/24/14, 20:39:59 GMT+2  :3   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:0
1/26/14, 0:36:29 GMT+2   Sleep                  Software Sleep pid=45 to DarkWake: Using AC
1/26/14, 0:38:34 GMT+2   WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: None
1/26/14, 9:54:42 GMT+2   Wake                   Wake [CDNVA] due to XHC1/HID Activity: Using AC
Total Sleep/Wakes since boot at 1/24/14, 20:39:59 GMT+2  :5
```

If your Mac supports Power Nap, you could try to disable Power Nap from System Preferences.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a lot of information in the system log.

Open the Console utility and this will allow you to easily search the system log for "sleep" and "wake".

The information is not easy to understand but if you do find some lines in the system log you can't understand feel free to update your question.

EHC1 is usually something to do with a USB device. Do you have an external drive attached to the machine? Is it powered via USB?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Activity Monitor and click View, Columns, make sure Prevent Sleep is checked and then look for what shows up that is listed.